# Can I Discern How Many Lines an HTML Element has Wrapped Contents To?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'd like to be able to tell whether a `<div>` containing a long string of text has wrapped it into 3, 4, or 5 lines, for example.

Comment: Have your attempts been unsuccessful? If so you should let us know what didn't work for you.

Comment: Won't that depend on what the browser window is sized to?  Are you looking for a function that will calculate this on the fly whenever you need it?

Comment: Is there a practical application for such information?

Comment: If you need to know the number of lines of a `p` tag just compare its height and its line-height

Comment: @DavidFregoli - In theory, each line box in the block can have a different height, so that won't work.

Comment: @Alohci what? ever heard of `line-height`?

Comment: @DavidFregoli - `line-height` gives the minimal height of each line box. Effectively the height of the strut. Each line box can be much taller than that.

Comment: It depends on the browser platform, how it's sized, etc.  Ideally, looking for a function that will calculate this on the fly, but it's okay if it just calculates once (upon render) and not every time the user resizes things.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted - the winning answer was what I needed and this code is now in production (for a side project of mine).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6maZ/) or `plugin`

```
$.fn.getLines=function(){  
var ele=this;  
var height=ele.height();   
var lineheight=parseInt(ele.css("line-height").replace("px",""));  
return Math.round(height/lineheight);  
};  
$(document).ready(function(){  
alert($("#element").getLines());  
});
```

Comment: This is amazing and does exactly what I want.  Thank you!